# How do I correctly show data after fetching from server?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which I am retrieving some data from server and then showing it to user.It involve following steps:

1. A list of names is showing to user in ListView.
2. User click on any ListView item.
3. Fetch the NID of the item clicked and then I invoke an AsyncTask class where I fetch the 
   data from server according to NID.
4. In AsyncTask class onPreExecute method I show an dialog to user indicating data is fetching.
5. Now I parse all data and put it in an Bean Class object.
6. In onPostExecute method I start an another Activity(nextactivity) and pass all data to this activity with Parcelable Intent.
7. Dismiss the dialog.
8. Now in onCreate method of this Activity(nextactivity) I show the data.

But here problem is that as data is large Activity(nextactivity) taking more time to load and ListView activity is shown to the user for 2-3 sec then nextActivty is shown to the user.

Here I am also giving you my code:

This is the method from which I invoke AsyncTask class to fetch data:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position).getNid(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

    if(rowItems.get(position).getNid()!=null){

        String[] params=new String[1];
        params[0]=rowItems.get(position).getNid();
        new RepresentativeDataAsynTask(RespresentativeList.this).execute(params);

    }
```

This is the AsyncTask class where I fetch all data:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        proDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        proDialog.setTitle("Support Manager");
        proDialog.setMessage("Fetching Details ...");
        proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        proDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected RepresentativeData doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject result = null;

        RepresentativeData representativeDetails = new RepresentativeData();
        try {
            result = client.reprentativeDetailNode(mContext.getString(R.string.Server),params[0]);
            //fetching all data by parsing result
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            error=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            error=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return representativeDetails;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RepresentativeData result) {
        Intent yourRepresentative = new Intent(mContext,YourRepresentative.class);
        yourRepresentative.putExtra("representative detail", result);
        proDialog.dismiss();
        mContext.startActivity(yourRepresentative);
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: bez you are doing in wrong why. you will need to first start `YourRepresentative` on ListView item Click and then inside `YourRepresentative` Activity onCreate's or onResume method start AsyncTask for getting data from server and show loadingbar also

Comment: Now I am starting YourRepresentative activity and then fetching the data from server and showing user an dialog while fetching.But now the raw layout is shown in background on progress dialog then data loads on YourRepresentative activity.

Comment: what u want ? i think it's working fine

Comment: I have done all setting in layout i.e, where I will display representative image,name,address etc.All these raw views were showing in background of progress dialog while fetching data from server.

Comment: Can you give me an prototype which I have to follow to do it.

Comment: Please tell me how do I remove this error..

Comment: Please provide me solution of this problem "I have done all setting in layout i.e, where I will display representative image,name,address etc.All these raw views were showing in background of progress dialog while fetching data from server"

Comment: then what u want? if you don't want to show all views before getting data from server then move all Ui update related code inside onPostExecute method

Comment: Yes you are saying to move "all UI related code in onPostExecute method".I am doing this only.But there are TextView and ImageView in my layout to which I have give some fake values.These values were showing to me when background fetching operation is working.

Comment: For Example: There is an Label(TextView) which is "Representative Name:" which is by default showing in background of dialog when background operation is working.

Comment: then try to move `setContentView` from onCreate to `onPostExecute` as : `YourRepresentative.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);` before accessing any elements from UI

Comment: Yeah I have found the solution.I have initially set the visibility of RelativeLayout to INVISIBLE the after loading the view dynamically I have set it to VISIBLE.It's work for me.Is this also the correct way of doing it.

Comment: yes it's right way as u are doing

Comment: In my app when user Logged In, then based on the user data in SERVER user can navigate to three possible activity i.e If user already registered,if user not register,if username and pass is incorrect.Now on which activity background I should perform all the background stuff.